# import dict from plain text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, dictionary, text

Let's say I have a dict in text file but I've lost the python code which created it.
Is it still possible to query info from python to this dict? 
What about creating a python script capable of reading the text sintaxis and create the dict structure? 
The file is huge, but it contains a correct python dict (of list, dicts and tuples)
Example:

```
{'CFGT': 'NONE',
 'FALN_GPH': {},
 'CDLAIN_ST': [],
 'CISN_IF': {'MT_DK': 'MFO',
                   'MD_GP': 'indi',
```

Is like a pickle dict, but human readable.

Comment: You probably want `json.load`

Comment: In what format is the dict stored? `json`? `pickle`? Just a python `repr`?

Comment: I think `json.load` will choke on tuples.  Try [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Whoops, that's right

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('dictionaryFile.txt','r') as filein:
    dict_from_file = eval(filein.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have some file `dict.txt` that has a plaintext dictionary and nothing else, you can use [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#module-pprint), the pretty-printing module

```
from pprint import pprint
from ast import literal_eval

with open('dict.txt') as f:
    pprint(literal_eval(f.read())
```

Comment: But I already have a nicely printed dict in `dict.txt`. I am trying to query info from this dict, without open it with a text editor.

Comment: @Evertthor_3 in that case just `d = literal_eval(f.read())` and then `d` is your `dict`