# How to create a dictionary from a txt file on Python

Tags: python, dictionary

This is the txt file content I have:

```
salesUnits:500
priceUnit:11
fixedCosts:2500
variableCostUnit:2
```

I need to create a dictionary in Python that will read the file and make the keys the `salesUnits` etc. and the values the numbers. The code I have so far will only print the variable cost per unit:

```
with open("myInputFile.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
myDict = {}
for line in content:
    myDict=line.rstrip('\n').split(":")
print(myDict)
```

How can I fix the code so that all key and value pairs show up? Thank you!

Comment: fix what code, you haven’t shown any code here

Comment: just added the code :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import dict from plain text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131837/import-dict-from-plain-text-file)

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting myDict each time you call `myDict=line.rstrip('\n').split(":")`. The pattern to add to a dictionary is dictionary[key] = value.

```
myDict = {}
with open("myInputFile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key_value = line.rstrip('\n').split(":")
        if len(key_value) == 2:
            myDict[key_value[0]]=key_value[1]
print(myDict)
```

outputs

```
{'fixedCosts': '2500', 'priceUnit': '11', 'variableCostUnit': '2', 'salesUnits': '500'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple dict comprehension will handle this:

```
with open('testinput.txt', 'r') as infile:
    dict = {
        line.strip().split(':')[0]:
        int(line.strip().split(':')[1])
            if line.strip().split(':')[1].isdigit()
        else
        line.strip().split(':')[1]
        for line in infile.readlines()}
print(dict)
```

Output:

```
{'salesUnits': 500, 'priceUnit': 11, 'fixedCosts': 2500, 'variableCostUnit': 2}
```

If you wish to bring the numbers in as simple strings, just use:

```
    dict = {
        line.strip().split(':')[0]:
        line.strip().split(':')[1]
        for line in infile.readlines()}
```

Note also that you can add handling for other data types or data formatting using additional variations of:

```
        int(line.strip().split(':')[1])
        if line.strip().split(':')[1].isdigit()
    else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myDict = {}

with open('dict.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')
        myDict[key] = value

print myDict
```

Output:

```
{'fixedCosts': '2500', 'priceUnit': '11', 'variableCostUnit': '2', 'salesUnits': '500'}
```